# Logging for ConnectedAppPlugin class

Tags: connected-apps, authentication, logging

I have a Connected App Handler Class (that extends the Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin) for one Connected App I am having. Use case is this class is used to set some additional attributes for which the standard customAttributes() method is overridden from the parent class. When a user logs in to Community, this class is invoked and sets the parameters.

However, much as I try to log some debug statements inside this class, I fail to see any logs generated for this class. I tried to turn logs on for the Portal User as well as the Trace settings on the Class itself, none worked. Can anyone point me in the right direction, what am I missing here? Which user do I log, to get the logs? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, in the Connected App Configuration, in the "Custom Connected App Handler" section, right below the "Apex Plugin Class", there is a field "Run As". It is the user which is set in this field, that is to be logged.